# How to create thread-safe servlet with spring when autowired attributes are obligated?

Tags: java, servlets, thread-safety, autowired, spring-jdbc

I am developing a Web-project that with spring and i have to guarantee thread-safety. My controller class has "@Autowired" attributes and according to my researches "@Autowired" implementations are singleton.

I have to use the "@Autowired" annotation within my controller class because my DBStuff class calls my DB procedure methods. (It's a Spring-Jdbc project and i implement the connection and db operations)

My controller class is like this:

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController{

    @Autowired
    private DBStuff dbStuff;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/application/new", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView applicationNew(Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //   ApplicationControllerTS is the class that implements servlet requirements. 
    //   Takes the request and fills the model etc. 
        return new ApplicationControllerTS(dbStuff).newAppl(locale, model, request);
    }



// and RequestMapping methods keep on going
}
```

Does the autowired DBStuff class fails this servlet to be thread-safe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `DBStuff` thread safe?

Comment: DBStuff is not thread-safe, but doesn't @Autowired annotation provide new instance per request in this servlet?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if `DBStuff` itself is thread-safe: if not, servlet is not as well.

Autowiring process itself occurs during webapp deployment (started by Spring `ContextLoaderListener`) and is guaranteed by Servlet spec to finish before any requests to that webapp servlets can be processed. I believe every sane Servlet container enforces inter-thread visibility of changes done in webapp's listener during its startup work to thread(s) passing client requests to a servlet.

So, again, answer to your question depends on thread safety of `DBStuff`.

Comment: DBStuff is not thread-safe, but doesn't @Autowired annotation provide new instance per request in this servlet?